# NASM Warning: Label in a row without a colon might be an error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to write a simple x86 assembly program which compares the unsigned values in `AL`, `BL` and `CL` respectively, and moves the smallest to `BH`. The code is actually given to me as an example and I am trying to make it run. I have typed in the example code as it was given to me as follows:

```
bits16
org 0x100
main:
mov al,7 ; In a big program one would read in the
mov bl,8 ; values for AL, BL and CL. Here we initialse
mov cl,5 ; the values for testing purposes
mov bh,al ; Mov AL to BH
cmp bh,bl ; Compare BH to BL
jbe label_1 ; If BH <= BL, jump to label_1
; else
mov bh,bl ; move BL to BH
label_1:
cmp bh,cl ; Compare BH to CL
jbe label_2 ; If BH <= CL, jump to label_2,
; else
mov bh,cl ; mov CL to BH
label_2:
; BH contains the smallest value
message: db 'Hello World',0ah,0dh,'$'
int 20h ; Terminate program
```

When compiling this, I get a *warning* saying:

"`label alone on a line without a colon might be an error`".

How do I fix this and get the code to compile and behave as described in the opening sentence? I understand that the compiler is hinting the answer to me, but I am new to x86 programming and would therefore appreciate some guidance. Additional explanations on what is a label, in this specific context, would also help.

Comment: You are missing a space on the first line, it should be `bits 16`. Note that the error message tells you the line number and you can then consult the manual to see what could be wrong with the particular construct.

Comment: When execution reaches `label_2` of your code it will fall through and attempt to execute the content of `message` as machine code. You should place the `int 20h` line directly after the `label_2` line to fix this.

Comment: @ecm Nice catch, now the program not only gets rid of the warning, but it runs without hanging, too. Admittedly, I added the print line in and it wasnt given to me. It was a way for me to see if the code was actually running. In my higher level programming mindset, I thought adding a print statement does no harm. It seems it does

Comment: Your message is only the *data* for displaying a line to the screen. The data belongs outside your code execution path. Keeping the fixed order you can add (between `label_2:` and `int 20h`) the three lines `mov dx, message` \ `mov ah, 09h` \ `int 21h` which are the *code* to display a line, which will be read from the address written to the `dx` register.

Comment: @ecm Ha, works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written the first instruction incorrectly and nasm is interpreting that as a label

```
bits16 ; no space between 'bits' and '16'
```

Change it to:

```
bits 16 ; space between 'bits' and '16'
```

#### What is a label?

A label is basically an identifier in the text segment of your code which represents a location. You can jump to it directly from anywhere in the program if it is a *global* label. How do you create a label?

```
label:
```

Just a sequence of characters with a colon at the end. Note that sometimes you will encounter labels that begin with a period `.`. Those are local labels.

#### Why do we use labels?

In simple words, Labels are used to create procedures and loops in assembly language mostly. You can do things without labels but then life would become very difficult.

Comment: No more warnings. But the program hangs when running it. Any ideas on what causes the hanging?

Comment: The code looks fine, have you given the complete code? Have you tried to run in a debugger? If you are just starting with assembly, I very strongly recommend getting a debugger and single stepping every program through it. It will teach you a lot of things, for example how flags get manipulated, how registers get effected, memory addressing. Without a debugger, learning assembly, especially for 16-bit is going to be *very* difficult.

Comment: I've got DEBUG installed. I will try tinker with that and see what I get